# why is the CDI Event generic?

Tags: java, events, jakarta-ee, cdi

let's assume I have an AccountService that notifies when an account is created or deleted. How would the 2 following implementation be of any difference?

```
@Stateless
public class AccountService {

    @Inject
    protected Event<AccountCreated> accountCreated;

    @Inject
    protected Event<AccountDeleted> accountDeleted;


    public UserAccount createAccount(...) {
        ...(do stuff)
        accountCreated.fire(new AccountCreated(...));
    }

    public UserAccount deleteAccount(...) {
        ...(do stuff)
        accountDeleted.fire(new AccountDeleted(...));
    }
}
```

and the simpler version:

```
@Stateless
public class AccountService {

    @Inject
    protected Event<Object> events;


    public UserAccount createAccount(...) {
        ...(do stuff)
        events.fire(new AccountCreated(...));
    }

    public UserAccount deleteAccount(...) {
        ...(do stuff)
        events.fire(new AccountDeleted(...));
    }

}
```

I'm currently using the 2nd approach, but am wondering if I'm not doing it right.

Comment: There seems to be a number of issues even before we get to your question, first the generic type information is erased at run-time so Event<AccountCreated> and Event<AccountDeleted> are the same thing. Also it seems you want to implement the observable design pattern and this is not the way you do it.

Comment: what's wrong about the way I do it?

Comment: Generics exist purely to aid you with static type checking (so that you don't accidentally fire a String or whatever). If you do not like that feature, feel free to <Object> everything as it will not make any difference at runtime. (And if you do: prepare for a lot of trouble in RL, as most people actually *like* static typechecks...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What your are asking about is mostly good practice or in some cases personal preference (or the voice of majority?).*

Both approaches would work, however the first one would be considered cleaner as it clearly shows what are you working with from the first look at it.

Furthermore, your second example is going to get messier if you start using qualifiers.

And if you were to ask similar question about `Instance<Object>`, then there would be additional reasons (to use first approach) - resolution checks during deployment, optimizations not working.